Analyse and identify features within a polygon/vector layer from a WMS layer
Regarding a project I'm doing, I am trying to see if this is possible and where to actually start.
Background: I have different WMS layers in QGIS loaded and a property line added as a vector layer.  Shown in this image the polygon line is called "tiltaksområde"

I can get the information from the vector layer by using "identify Features" when clicking around like this image

Is there a way to run a query of some sort that uses the polygon/vector layer as a boundary and reports what types of features are found within the polygon, and preferably if more than one, it calculates a percentage of the total area of the vector layer?

No, a WMS is a picture of the map, you need to find a WFS data feed

This tutorial might help. https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/training_manual/online_resources/wfs.html#lesson-web-feature-services
